# How to decouple microservice call in an on-demand action?

Tags: microservices

Imagine we have microservice *A* and *B*. *A* has and endpoint in its rest API that will execute some CPU-bound operations and will formulate the return afterwards based on the actual state of some objects. This operation is actually requested for a bunch of other microservices. I can't see how I could decouple microservice *A* (consider this endpoint for the sake of this question) from its actual callers using a materialized view or an event bus.

As I read that any coupling between microservices should be avoided, what is usually done decouple MSs in cases like this?

Comment: It really depends on the problem area.  I.e. can you deal with the idea of _eventual consistency_?  The thing to think about is whether you have to make synchronous calls across services, and why.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch thanks for the anwer. No, I can't deal with eventual consistency in this case. This data needs to be always as precise as it can possibly be. Are there cases where direct coupling microservices make sense? Or we should always go for a decoupled approach?

Comment: What benefit do you hope to gain by using microservices if you are expecting everything to be tightly coupled together?     Microservices provide clean separation and isolation of functionality when properly decoupled, which should lead to better fault tolerance, deployment, scalability etc.   If your services will all be coupled together then you risk needing to manage a "distributed monolith", with all the additional complexity and infrastructure to contend with on top, including harder testing & debugging while not having any of the microservice benefits.  So i would ask "what's the point?"

Answer (score 1):

Microservices are an eventually consistent model, it can be a very short "eventually" but microservices are inefficient by design. If you really need up to the millisecond or faster, you need a monolith, which isn't a bad thing. Microservices are great when a second isn't that big of deal, if a comment doesn't show for someone until the next auto update there isn't anything bad happening. If you want to display stock information for day traders or high frequency trading, then that second is an eternity and could be the difference between profit and loss.

Also keep in mind a lot of companies say they want need low latency up to the millisecond data, but they really don't need that, and aren't willing to do what is needed to actually achieve that in the first place. If given the choice of X time for a project with a second or so of uncertainty vs 10x for a more robust solution that provides millisecond level accuracy, many people realize that latency isn't super important.

Answer (score 0):

**Best Practice**

Best practice is to use messages and be OK with eventual consistency.  The reasons for this recommendation include:

- It minimizes direct coupling between services, making them easier to deploy independently
- In most cases there are follow on activities that do not need to be in the same transaction

**Reality**

There are some activities that have to be called synchronously.  For example, and authentication service needs to pull the actual user records from the user management service to create the correct token.

Generally, you want to minimize these interactions as much as possible.  The risk of cascade failure goes up as services directly depend on each other.

If you have a large number of cross-business responsibility transactions that require several services to coordinate, then that business need is an impediment to going to microservices.  You will have to seriously evaluate whether the assumptions that the business rules were built on require "transactional" security.  If so, stay monolith.

**Inter-dependency Complexity**

In the Mythical Man Month by Frederick Brooks (published 1975), Brooks has a formula to underscore the growth in complexity when you introduce more people into a team.  The same formula works for understanding the complexity of introducing dependencies between services:

```
complexity = n(n-1)/2
```

Please consider this formula as you create synchronous calls from one service to another.  If you have a small number of direct dependencies, then the complexity is still low.  For example, if you only have 3 services that need to directly call other services your complexity would be 3 (3 * 2 / 2).  However if you have 20 services calling each other, then your complexity is 90 (20 * 19 / 2).

In this case the complexity is the likelihood that you will get into a stability problem.  Higher numbers are worse for stability.